# Connect 4 PVP Function

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, connect

I can't seem to find something that specifically answers my question. I am looking for a solution to my problem. The connect 4 player versus player seems to just ask the first player to drop then the second player to drop, but the first if statement is no longer true so it continues to ask the second player to drop. I am using eclipse for mac osx although the game is programmed for ASCII character set.

```
display();
int hold;
int hold2 = 0;
int charsPlaced = 0;
bool gamewon = false;
char player = 15;
string r;

while (!gamewon)
{
    if (hold2 != -1)
    {
        if (player == 15)
        {
            cout << ax << " what column would you like to drop in?";
            player = 178;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << bx << " what column would you like to drop in?";
            player = 176;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are `15`, `178`, `176`, `hold` and `hold2`?

Comment: 15, 178, 176 are all character values for ASCII. That will be the symbol that the player drops into the grid. The hold and hold2 are variables inside of the player vs. player function. This is the source file.

Comment: The hold and hold2 functions are basically there to hold the value (column) that the player would like to drop in...

Comment: for the sake of simplicity use a `bool bPlayer1` which is `true` when it's player1's turn and `false` when it's player2's. And then ask the player whose turn is what column does he want to drop the chip in, drop it and negate `bPlayer1` and do the same thing on and on until someone wins

Comment: I appreciate the response although I'm finding the suggestion a little confusing.

Comment: Could you maybe express it in code, if you get the chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch the players' turn **after each action**. If P1 took an action, you need to update the "turn" so that the **next time the code loops it will ask for P2**. Then, after you've done the stuff you need to do for P2, you need to update the "turn" so that **the next time it loops it will ask for P1 action**.

Here's a different approach on your code by using an `enum`. You can use a `bool` type variable which is `false` for P1 and `true` for P2, or an `int` that's 1 or 2, but that's a bit harder to understand from the outisde.

```
// omitted code
enum PlayerTurn { ePlayer1 = 0, ePlayer2 };

// omitted code

PlayerTurn plTurn = ePlayer1;
while (!gamewon)
{
    if (pTurn == ePlayer1)
    {
        cout << ax << " what column would you like to drop in?";
        // TODO: stuff to do for Player #1
    }
    else
    {
        cout << bx << " what column would you like to drop in?";
        // TODO: stuff to do for Player #2
    }

    // TODO: decide if game has been won, mechanics etc.

    // move to the next player without overflowing the 2 possible values (0 and 1)
    plTurn = (plTurn + 1) % 2; 
}
```

Then, on your `display()` function, you can show any ASCII character you wish.

Comment: Thanks you! You have been very helpful!